# Single JPQL query or criteria for multiple combination input

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

i use below JPQL query to check if a student exist for the name and id combination.

```
select id from student where name='name' and id=1
```

Now i need to check 1000 combinations at a time.
Running the same query 1000 times is performance threat.
And i am not sure if we can make a single query with 1000 combination.
These 1000 combinations are coming from UI, so joins not possible.
can we achieve this with JPQL/Criteria ? (without temp tables/plsql)

Comment: Can you show us what the full query would like look, for, say 3 combinations?

Comment: some thing like this `select id from student where (name='name' and id=1) or (name='name2' and id=2) or (name='name3' and id=3)` . any simple way of doing this for 1000 combinations

Comment: What database are you using?  You could always fall back to building the query manually either as JPQL or native SQL.

Comment: jpa 2.0(hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar) and oracle

Comment: `'select id from student where (name='name' and id=1) or (name='name2' and id=2) or (name='name3' and id=3)`

this seems to be worked. but is that good solution for 1000 combinations?

Comment: Well if you can build the query you need dynamically and run it, then what is the problem?  It strikes me as odd that the UI is sending back so much information, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do it without a performance trouble, but, you can improve it using union all statment, like:

```
select id from student where name='name' and id=1 union all select id from student where name='name2' and id=2
```